# Function to split text in cell and create column

Tags: split, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with rows like this:

```
| sth1, sth2 |
| sth4       |
| sth1, sth3 |
| sth4       |
```

And I want to split each cell in this column and create new column like this:

```
| sth1 |
| sth2 |
| sth4 |
| sth1 |
| sth3 |
| sth4 |
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Was my answer of use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Google Apps Script, it can be done with this little script:

### Code

```
function splitColumn(range) {
  var output = [];

  for(var i in range) {
    var split = range[i][0].split(",");

    if(split.length == 1) {
      output.push([split[0]]);
    } else {
      for(var j in split) {
        output.push([split[j]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;  
}
```

### Usage

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[row content to column](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdDRpQXhSdDZuQ01rVks3Yy1Xa3M1N0E&usp=sharing)**

### Remark

Add this script by selecting `Tools` from the menu, followed by `Script editor`. Paste the script and press the save button and you're on the go.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `sth1, sth2` is in B1, does not *require* a script:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(textjoin(",",,B1:B4),", ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to split a particular column.

```
function SplitColumnValues(sheet_name, column_index, delimiter) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var range = sheet.getRange(1,column_index,lastRow-1, 1);
  range.splitTextToColumns(delimiter);
}
```

---

The function takes sheet name, Column that you want to split and delimiter.

First, get the reference sheet

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
```

next line will get the number of rows that are in the column that needs to be split

```
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
```

next get the range(i.e. the column that needs to be split) and then split that range using 'splitTextToColumn'

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1,column_index,lastRow-1, 1);
range.splitTextToColumns(delimiter);
```