# GAS Split one cell and fill down another

Tags: google-apps-script, split, google-sheets

I have the following situation:

```
Column G              Column H
|Black, Brown, Grey| | dog |
|Calico            | | cat |
|Green, Blue       | | bird|
| ...              | | ... |
```

I would like to split and fill down to this:

```
Column G  Column H
|Black | |dog |
|Brown | |dog |
|Grey  | |dog |
|Calico| |cat |
|Green | |bird|
|Blue  | |bird|
|...   | | ...|
```

Looking at the script to split a comma delineated cell ([Function to split text in cell and create column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595801/function-to-split-text-in-cell-and-create-column)) I can follow the split but it's the filling down portion that I am having trouble with.  I understand I should set up a `while` loop with the first cell as var = i and the second cell as var = j.  Dump the split contents of i to an array and then fill down the array.length.  However, I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I'm pretty new to JS and GAS so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

-JH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a custom function that should work for you:

```
/** 
* Splits the array by commas in the column with given index, by given delimiter
* @param {A2:B20}  range Range reference
* @param {2}  colToSplit Column index
* @param {","}  delimiter Character by which to split
* @customfunction
*/


function advancedSplit(range, colToSplit, delimiter) {
var resArr = [], row;
range.forEach(function (r) {
    r[colToSplit-1].replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(\d|\w)/g,", ").split(delimiter)
        .forEach(function (s) {
            row = [];
            r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
                row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
            })
            resArr.push(row);
        })
})
return resArr.filter(function (r) {
    return r.toString()
        .replace(/,/g, "")
})
}
```

This function can be used like this:

[image]